# How do I push a pdf from Overleaf to GitHub?

Tags: overleaf

I know Overleaf (v2) can push directly to GitHub but it would be a lot more efficient if it could push a PDF version too. Is there a way to do that without downloading the pdf and then having to push it manually?

Comment: This question is better suited for https://stackoverflow.com/ or contact [Overleaf support](https://www.overleaf.com/contact).

Comment: I'm not sure why questions about (say) TeXnicCenter or Texmaker are considered on-topic, but questions about Overleaf are not.

Comment: Just a simple alternative: push only the TeX file, but set up a CI build which creates the PDF with every push.

Comment: It is ridiculous that a question like this is just closed with no answers and no links to similar questions. This is the top result on google when I search "overleaf github push pdf". Whoever closed this thread as off-topic is actively doing the community a disservice.

Comment: @Ben10: If you have an answer, please flag this question for moderator review and it can be opened. Other ways include posting something on [Meta.TeX.SE](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com), or casting a re-open vote yourself. The main reason for closing it relates to the fact that it's off-topic for *this* site, and perhaps better-suited elsewhere, where programmers of the Overleaf back-end can provide support. We - [tex.se] - deal with TeX-related issues/code, not programming of software and feature requests (which this seems to be).

Comment: @Werner I think it is pretty self-explanatory that this post should be reopened: at least 11 users want an answer to this question, even if the answer if "you can't do it". If you can re-open, please do so. I don't know how to cast a re-open vote, nor do I know if there's a better place for this question. All I know is everyone on the internet comes to this site for this specific question, and they will all be frustrated because somehow it's "off-topic"